# python split image in overlapping and rotating tiles

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am doing a image classification. I have very imbalanced data. I am trying couple of approaches to overcome the imbalanced data issue. one of them is oversampling the minority class.
The images that i have are already in high resolution(1392x1038), so i am splitting them into 348x256 size 16 tiles. As in oversampling, you simply replicate the minority classes. I was thinking of splitting the image into overlapping tiles with stride 1 or 2, so i would have slighlty different images and it would also help me in oversampling. Following code splits the images into specified number of defined size overlapping tiles

```
for i in range(0, count):
        start_row_idx = random.randint(0, img_height-target_height-1)
        start_col_idx = random.randint(0, img_width-target_width-1)

        if mode == 'rgb':
            patch = img_array[start_row_idx:(start_row_idx+target_height), start_col_idx:(start_col_idx+target_width), :]
        else:
            patch = img_array[start_row_idx:(start_row_idx+target_height), start_col_idx:(start_col_idx+target_width)]
        patches.append(patch)
        idxs.append((start_row_idx, start_col_idx))
```

how can I make it work for rotating overlapping tiles with defined number of tiles and size.

Edited Question:
In following image, the black squares shows the horizontal stride and tile which is I am able to get. I want to get the red color squares in that shape. I think, with red color type cropping i would be able to get more images for oversampling.

[image]

Comment: By examining your code, there's a potential for tiles to overlap since the starting row and column can be anywhere in the image.  In other words, it is possible that you can generate random row and column indices such that they could be near each other within the target width and height which can generate overlapping tiles.  Could you clarify what you mean when you say "overlapping" tiles in light of this fact?

Comment: you are right. its is doing what i intended to do. but as i might need to generate more random tiles and this code would only does the stride in horizonatally and vertically. I was wondering if we can rotate the rectangle/tile few degrees and then make the tiles.

Comment: So is your question now to introduce rotation into the tiles too? What packages are you using for the image manipulation? OpenCV? PIL? Scikit image?

Comment: opencv, but i am open to other packages too

Comment: I'm fine with OpenCV.  I can write an answer that will provide rotations to your crop if you like.  I do recommend changing your question though

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: I was wondering if you have any suggestion for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360795/cell-boundaries-detection problem!

Comment: I tried to code and it does rotate the the image. I think i wasnt clear in my question. I have updated my question.

Comment: With your code, the same tiles images get rotated but with black backgrounds on the size(rotated spaces)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can get those tiles in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed above, you have tiles that have the potential of being overlapped so this is already being addressed.  What is missing are rotating the tiles too.  We will need to specify a random angle of rotation so that we can generate a random angle first.

After, this is simply a matter of applying an affine transform that is purely a rotation to the tiles then appending to the list.  The problem with rotating images in OpenCV is that when you do rotate the image, it is subject to cropping so you don't get the entire tile contained in the image once you rotate.

I used the [following post as inspiration](http://john.freml.in/opencv-rotation) to address this issue so that when you do rotate, the image is fully contained.  Take note that the image will expand in dimensions in order to accommodate for the rotation and to keep the entire image contained in the rotated result.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rotate_about_center(src, angle):
    h, w = src.shape[:2]
    rangle = np.deg2rad(angle)  # angle in radians
    # now calculate new image width and height
    nw = (abs(np.sin(rangle)*h) + abs(np.cos(rangle)*w))
    nh = (abs(np.cos(rangle)*h) + abs(np.sin(rangle)*w))
    # ask OpenCV for the rotation matrix
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((nw*0.5, nh*0.5), angle, 1)
    # calculate the move from the old centre to the new centre combined
    # with the rotation
    rot_move = np.dot(rot_mat, np.array([(nw-w)*0.5, (nh-h)*0.5,0]))
    # the move only affects the translation, so update the translation
    # part of the transform
    rot_mat[0,2] += rot_move[0]
    rot_mat[1,2] += rot_move[1]
    return cv2.warpAffine(src, rot_mat, (int(math.ceil(nw)), int(math.ceil(nh))), flags=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
```

You use this function and call this with a random angle then save the patch when you're done.  You'll also need to specify a maximum angle of rotation of course.

```
import random
max_angle = 20 # +/- 20 degrees maximum rotation
patches = []
idxs = []
for i in range(0, count):
    start_row_idx = random.randint(0, img_height-target_height-1)
    start_col_idx = random.randint(0, img_width-target_width-1)

    # Generate an angle between +/- max_angle
    angle = (2*max_angle)*random.random() - max_angle

    if mode == 'rgb':
        patch = img_array[start_row_idx:(start_row_idx+target_height), start_col_idx:(start_col_idx+target_width), :]
    else:
        patch = img_array[start_row_idx:(start_row_idx+target_height), start_col_idx:(start_col_idx+target_width)]

    # Randomly rotate the image
    patch_r = rotate_about_center(patch, angle)

    # Save it now
    patches.append(patch_r)
    idxs.append((start_row_idx, start_col_idx))
```